# SqlException not getting caught with try-catch

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I am creating an app where I am calling WebMethods through my controller class to control my GUI. The problem is that I get a popup saying that I have unhandled SqlExceptions when I try to add an object with a primary key that is already in use. The problem occurred when I switched to calling the methods through my soap client instead of my DataAccessLayer. Where do I need to put my catch statements for them to work with my WebMethod calls, as they did with my DataAccessLayer? Here is my controller and an insert statement I am trying to use:

```
using BrothersWhoCodeLibrary;
using CodesWhoBrosServiceReference;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static CodesWhoBrosServiceReference.CodesWhoBrosServiceSoapClient;

namespace WinFormsAppBrothersWhoCode
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       DataAccessLayer dataAccess = new DataAccessLayer();
        CodesWhoBrosServiceSoapClient client = new CodesWhoBrosServiceSoapClient(EndpointConfiguration.CodesWhoBrosServiceSoap);


        public Form1()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();
            PopulateDataGridViewWithCustomers();
            PopulateDataGridViewWithStores();
            PopulateDataGridViewWithSuppliers();
            PopulateDataGridViewWithProducts();
            PopulateDataGridViewWithOrderDetails();
            PopulateDataGridViewWithStock();
            PopulateDataGridViewWithOrders();
            //drafting methods
            //public void NewCustomer() 
            //{ }

        }

 private void addStoreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string newStoreName = storeName.Text;
            string newPhoneNbr = storePhoneNbr.Text;
            string newEmail = storeEmail.Text;

            try
            {
                client.InsertStore(newStoreName, newEmail, newPhoneNbr);
                PopulateDataGridViewWithStores();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Number == 2627)
                {
                    storeLabel.Text = "Please choose another name, a store named " + newStoreName + " already exists";

                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeName.Text))
                {
                    storeLabel.Text = "Please enter a name";
                }
                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(storePhoneNbr.Text))
                {
                    storeLabel.Text = "Please enter a phonenumber";
                }
                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeEmail.Text))
                {
                    storeLabel.Text = "Please enter an email";
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you doing input validation after you tried to insert the data?

Comment: I am rather new to this so I do not understand what you mean, should my if statements come before my client.insert call?

Comment: He is refering to this part of the code:  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeName.Text))
                {
                    storeLabel.Text = "Please enter a name";
                }

This should actually not be in the exception, but rather before you perform any actions such as insert, update etc.

Comment: Ok, I understand, I guess that is why I have been able to add empty rows into my table. But will changing this make any difference to catching the exception?

Comment: No it won't make a difference there. But it isn't a sql error, those are data errors. I would change that catch so that it catches any exception myself. Change it from SqlException to Exception. Then you will capture anything that fails.

Comment: But how do I get it to catch my sql errors, seeing as it is that which the app is complaining about, e.g. trying to add an object with an existing primary key?

Comment: There are different levels of granualarity for exceptions. If you just want to catch all exceptions use (Exception ex) instead of the (SqlException ex). After you determined the error, you can refine Exception handling later on. Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/exception-handling) to deepen your understanding about exceptions :)